# how can I fetch the longitude and latitude from a specific point on my mapview in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I have a `MKMapView` in my app and currently I'm fetching the center point of this map by using:

```
longitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude
latitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude
```

but now instead of taking the center point of the map I want to take a specific point that is 100px below the top edge of my mapview. So normally I would use something like:

```
longitude = mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude
latitude = mapView.(centerCoordinate+100px).latitude
```

But that's not how that works apparently. Is there any way of fetching a specific point from mkmapview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let frame = mapView.frame
let myPoint = CGPointMake(frame.midX, 100)
let myCoordinate = mapView.convertPoint(myPoint, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = myCoordinate
annotation.title = "My Point"

mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the the MapKit method:

```
convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:
```